# 2nd Normal Form

Tags: database, normalization

I have a question:

Considering a relation R{***A***,***B***,***C***,D,E,F} with the next set of functional dependencies `{ABC->DEF,D->E,ABC->A}.` A, B and C are Prymary Keys.

Can you explain me why this is on 2nd NF? Thanks.

Comment: {ABC} is a candidate key. It's the only candidate key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can you explain me why this is on 2nd NF?

I'm not quite sure what "why this is on 2nd NF" means. (Typo?) But the relation R is not in 3NF, because there's a transitive dependency: ABC->D, and D->E. So relation R *must* be in either 1NF or 2NF.

Relation R is in 2NF if and only if

- it's in 1NF, and
- there are no partial key dependencies.

ABC->A might *look* like a partial key dependency, but it's not, because "A" is a prime attribute. (ABC->A is a trivial dependency, because A->A.) The non-prime attributes are {DEF}. None of those attributes are functionally dependent on only part of any candidate key (a more general way of saying they're not functionally dependent on part of *this* relation's primary key).

So relation R is in 2NF.

Comment: Can you give me an example of a partial key example in this case? Thanks.

Comment: If C->Z were a functional dependency here, and {ABC} were the only candidate key, C->Z would be a partial key dependency. Z is dependent on part of a candidate key.